# JSON javascript display value undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object returned which looks like this

```
[
    {
        "competition": {
            "name": "Premier League",
        },
        "nextState": 1,
        "team_id": 1
}, {
        "competition": {
            "name": "Premier League",
        },
        "nextState": 1,
        "team_id": 2
}
]
```

This a slimmed down version of the JSON, I am trying to access say the team_id

```
result = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
    console.log(result);

    $('#test').append(result);

    alert(result[0].team_id);
```

All I seem to get is undefined, am I not access this correctly?

Many thanks

Comment: `"[".team_id` will always be undefined. Don't stringify it

Comment: You're transforming a data structure (JSON) into a linear chain of character (string). No wonder you can't access the data structure anymore. Nowadays, everyone stringifies their JSON for some reason, before sending it, after receiving it, all the time, and that's a trend I just can't explain.

Comment: thanks guys, all answers were very helpful the accepted answer was the fiirst though thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stringified your object `result` to a string. So for sure you can not access the attributes anymore.

Use a second variable for the stringified result:

```
var result_stringified = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
console.log(result_stringified);
$('#test').append(result_stringified);
alert(result[0].team_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var data = [{
      "competition": {
        "name": "Premier League",
      },
      "nextState": 1,
      "team_id": 1
    }, {
      "competition": {
        "name": "Premier League",
      },
      "nextState": 1,
      "team_id": 2
    }]



    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      alert(this.team_id);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing `undefined` was because you have already stringified your JSON object into a String already. So a String != Array, hence doing String[0] would give you undefined and obviously doing `.team_id` on an undefined would still be `undefined`.

What you got there is an `array` of javascript `objects`.

To access a specific `team_id` property of an object, you will first have to access that `object` from the array then use the `.team_id` notation or the `["team_id"]` syntax on the `object`.

**Example:**

```js
var items =[
    {
        "competition": {
            "name": "Premier League",
        },
        "nextState": 1,
        "team_id": 1
    },
    {
        "competition": {
            "name": "Premier League",
        },
        "nextState": 1,
        "team_id": 2
    }
]

items.forEach(item => { console.log("item_id= " + item.team_id + ", competition= " + item.competition.name); });
```

What I have done for the above example is that I am using the `forEach` API to go through individual items of the `items` array then I am printing details of the `object` by accessing its `team_id` and the nested `competition.name` properties.

Just incase you are interested in the `.forEach()` API.

**See:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach